# Udefined variable while adding column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, alter-table, laravel-7

```
$save=$data->save();

if ($save) {
   Schema::table('users', function($table) {
      $table->string($data->id);
   });
   return back()->withInput()->with('message','Carrier Created Successfully');
}
```

И saved few data in a table than want to add column with id of that data in users table but getting error:

> undefined variable $data

and line highlighted is :

```
$table->string($data->id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `use` for using other variable from one function to another

```
Schema::table('users', function($table) use ($data) {
      $table->string($data->id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables outside the inner function are not available inside the inner function. For that you need to pass the variable using `use`

```
$save=$data->save();

if ($save) {
   Schema::table('users', function($table) use ($data) {
      $table->string($data->id);
   });
   return back()->withInput()->with('message','Carrier Created Successfully');
}
```

Now `$data` should be available there inside the function.